# how to store sensor points in array

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

hello I am working in expo, in my sensor app  I am getting some points I want to store these points in an array how can I do this I have tried these codes but always print a new array with no. in a new line
[image]

here is my code

```
const [x , setX] = useState([]);
 const subscribe = Gyroscope.addListener( async({x , y , z , }) => {
        setX([x])
        setY(y)
        setZ(z)
    })
    // let array = []
   let m = x
   console.log('my array is',m)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just replace the setX([x]) with

```
setX((prev) => [x, ...prev])
```

full code:

```
const [x , setX] = useState([]);
const subscribe = Gyroscope.addListener( async({x , y , z , }) => {
        setX((prev) => [x, ...prev])
        setY(y)
        setZ(z)
})
// let array = []
let m = x
console.log('my array is',m)
```